# What is the SQL statement (Oracle) to alter column to DATE with default SYSDATE ?

Tags: sql, oracle

I got a table name: `kundorder`

And a column name: `datum`. I want to change data typ to (DATE, SYSDATE), but I cant get it to work.

Comment: "*cant get it to work*" is not a valid error message. And besides: `sysdate` is **not** a datatype, it's a function. To change the datatype of a column use alter table. All documented in the manual: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_3001.htm#CJAHHIBI

Comment: What is it now? What format is it in? What code are you running?

Comment: ok sorry, im new to this.. but i think i got it right now: ALTER TABLE kundorder
MODIFY datum DEFAULT SYSDATE;

Answer (score 11):

I think it should look like this

```
ALTER TABLE kundorder MODIFY datum DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE
```

That way you say that `datum` got to be of type `date` but if this is already the case of course

```
ALTER TABLE kundorder MODIFY datum DEFAULT SYSDATE
```

works also, letting the type of the field `datum` the same just making sure default is SYSDATE.