# Oracle auto add current date

Tags: sql, oracle

I want create a table 'product' and have a column `date`, is it possible that current date will be added when I add some info to table?

If yes please example of this table

```
create table products (
id number not null,
date number not null
);
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12129051/what-is-the-sql-statement-oracle-to-alter-column-to-date-with-default-sysdate

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Assuming that

1. Your column is not actually named `date` since that is a reserved word
2. Your column is actually defined as a `date` rather than as a `number`
3. You want to populate the column when you insert a new row

you can define a default value for the column.

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  create table products (
  2  id number not null,
  3  dt date   default sysdate not null
  4* )
SQL> /

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> insert into products( id ) values( 1 );

1 row created.

SQL> select * from products;

        ID DT
---------- ---------
         1 20-NOV-12
```

If you want to modify the `dt` column when you `UPDATE` the row, you would need a trigger

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_products
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON products
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  :new.dt := sysdate;
END;
```

A trigger will override any value passed in as part of the `INSERT` or `UPDATE` statement for the `dt` column.  A default value will not.

Comment: I ran almost same as your first sample where you added new column set to default sysdate.  That updated all prior records to sysdate.  Is there a way to leave them null, but yet let all new records auto-default to sysdate?

Comment: Forgot to mention, I was doing ALTER TABLE to add new date column (not creating new table).