# Setting Default Date Value PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl

I am using pl/sql.  I am creating a table using the data type DATE, and I need to set a default value to today's date.
Last_date DATE default ***_***
How can I made the default value of the date today?

Comment: A `create table` statement is SQL, not PL/SQL

Comment: Please check the following link


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13479229/oracle-auto-add-current-date

Answer (score 1):

Like this for date with time

```
create table x
( column_with_date date default sysdate
)
```

This without time

```
create table x
( column_with_date date default trunc(sysdate)
)
```

Comment: Hi. Did this work for you? Please mark the question as answered if this resolved your issue.